# React native how to add bottom tab menu after clicking login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to react-native and I am confused about routing / navigation. Basically, I've got 4 screens which are `Login`, `Register`, `Home` and `Links`. The `Register` and `Login` are already set. I used `stackNavigator` in order for the user to click back whether they want to register or not. But when I click login, I want to redirect the user to my `Home` screen which has a tab menu or container. My current output for this code is that when I do register, I can go back to the login by pressing the text I made. Can someone show me or provide me some link on how to do the bottom tab when I successfully logged in?

My current output is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVU20.jpg

I utilized `onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Route')}}` functionality from my components to switch screen.

Here is some of my code:

AppNavigation.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Register from '../screens/RegisterScreen'
import Login from '../screens/LoginScreen'

const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login},
    Register: { screen: Register },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)
export default AppNavigation
```

AuthNavigation.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Login from '../screens/LoginScreen'
const AuthNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
)
export default AuthNavigation
```

index.js (inside from ./navigation/index.js)

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import AuthNavigation from './AppNavigation'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Auth: AuthNavigation,
    App: AppNavigation
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Auth',
  }
)
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)
export default AppContainer
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

My current directory

[image]

I followed the auth pattern here 
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/how-authentication-flow-works-in-react-native-apps-using-react-navigation-4-x-a30bb4d9e5d6

Answer (score 1):

**try this syntax on onPress**

```
onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}
```

**your ques: how to do the bottom tab when I successfully logged in?**

create Home Component

When your login is successfully then

```js
if(login is successfully){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}
```

Comment: i changed my navigation to v 5.x so my code kinda change a bit. can you teach me how to do it ?

Comment: do you have a repo for it something like a auth flow?

Comment: Sorry, @Vince I can't understand what are you say. please explain with me

Comment: i mean do you have something like a repository for auth flow using tabs in react native?

Comment: sure @Vince this is my public repository https://github.com/Awadhesh786/ReactNativeExample

Comment: does that work with expo? because im using expo. Btw here is my repository for this one
https://github.com/VinceSanityyy/react-native-expo.git . I used the preset tabs for expo and i created a login page. but i cant seem to implement to see the login page first then when the user is authenticated, it will show the home wich has tabs

Comment: Sorry, @Vince I've no idea of the expo. I worked on react-native-cli

Comment: okay i see. expo is just like react native. they got same code except that you can test anywhere with your device i think

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax to be able to navigate between the components you want.

```
if(login == true){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  // You can use this.props.navigation.push('Home'); as well
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/routing-in-react-native-apps-and-how-to-configure-your-project-with-react-navigation-library-d8d58005bfe9) is a good reference to navigation and routing in general using React Native.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do this in React Navigation v5 and v6 are as followed. Setup a global auth provider with createContext. Then use that in a switch statement to determine whether you should use the Auth stack or the main navigation stack. The main navigation stack (AppStack in this case) would be a bottom tab navigator nested inside a stack navigator with the initialRouteName set to 'Home' (or whatever your home screen is called in the stack nav).

The Provider can look something like this

```
export const AuthUserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And the Nested stack navigators with switch statement should look something like this:

```
export default function Routes() {
  const Root = createStackNavigator();
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthUserContext);

//....authentication hooks

return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Root.Navigator
        {user ?
          (<Root.Screen name='AppStack' component={AppStack} />)
          :
          (<Root.Screen name='AuthStack' component={AuthStack} />)
        }
      <Root.Navigator>
    <NavigationContainer>
)
```